# Jenkins pipeline starting and stopping a runtime environment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins pipeline script for an job. I want to start a runtime env before a stage execution and stop it after the stage finishes. E.g. start a mongo db before the stage and stop after the stage which uses mongodb  ( Don't want to put start and stop inside the stage script).

I found wrap option in pipeline but it has some predefined option and I cannot start my runtime inside it.

I also tried using a parallel stage and started the runtime in it. But was not able to stop the stage(runtime) when the maine stage finished

Any other way to achieve the same

Answer (score 0):

Some of these types of actions you may want to delegate down to your scripts instead of orchestrating at the Jenkins Pipeline leve, so should be kept in mind. One way would be to use a `try`/`catch`/`finally` or `try`/`finally` structure to control the build flow.

```
try {
  // Prep database
  stage('mystage') {
    // Do work that may fail
  }
finally {
  // Clean up actions
}
```

You can also use combinations of the `sh`/`bat` step that have the `returnStatus` and `returnStdOut` options to orchestrate your build pipeline.